# What is the "non-Java object" type visible in the Heap tool of the Android SDK?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I'm fighting against memory leaks and I use the Heap tool in eclipse for this.

As you can see on this screenshot http://hpics.li/b7c60de, the bigger part of my memory is used by ***non-Java object*** but I don't know what is that type. Is it C++ code, resources objects like images ... ?

Comment: 241 megs for an application is, lots. I assume you've turned on the large heap request available in 3.0+ ? Do you actually need that much, or is the result of your leaks?

Comment: To add to @FunkTheMonk's comment, if you are building a game, you will generally want to use the Android NDK (native code - C i think).

Comment: @FunkTheMonk : Yes I know it's a lot. And yes this is a result of the leaks. At begining my application needs about 20Mb. This number grows of about 10 Mo every time I switch to another Activity.

Comment: @Phil : Thanks I know the NDK but I should not need this because I don't build a game. This huge amount of memory used is due of my performance test.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment suggests that you're leaking at least one reference to each of your Activities. Do you have any static Drawables, Views, Contexts, etc?
Do you have any inner non-static classes (they keep a reference to the outer class)?
Do you keep any Drawables, Views, Contexts, etc in your Application, or anywhere else that has a longer lifetime than the Activity.

These are the 3 main things that usually leak Activities.

Drawables, Views, Adapters and various other things keep references to the Context that they are created in (it's parent Activity), so if you're keeping them alive longer than the Activity itself, the Activity stays in memory.

This [video](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=_CruQY55HOk) explains it all, and how to use a couple of tools to help you debug the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.    

Yes I have at least one class (but not activity) that have static Context. I also have one non-static inner class that use an attribute (a context object) of the outer class.    

I use some adapters, maybe the problem comes for this.    

For information I tried to unbind all references of the every Activities when they destroy themselves but it didn't work ([idea found here](http://1gravity.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=71)).    

Finaly, I had a look on this video that I already saw. I will try to look in the HPROF file.